# importing python modules and packages in different sub-directories of the same project

Tags: python, structure, project, project-structure, project-structuring

I'd like to figure out the cleanest and preferably self contained way to use my packages in scripts that are in a different directory to the package itself.

The example problem is as follows:

The modules in `lib` need to both be imported, and run as a script.

My project directory is as below and I'm having two issues:

1. in `lib/api.py`, I want to read in `data_files/key.txt` correctly when `api.py` is called or imported
2. in `testing_script.py` I want to import and use `lib/get_data.py`

I can't seem to find a clean way to do this, does this mean my project is structured in a non-pythonic way?

Thanks for the help.

```
my-project-git
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├─── my_project
│   ├── data_files
│   │   ├── key.txt
│   │   ├── mappings.csv
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── api.py
│   │   └── get_data.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── testing_script.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Comment: I proposed an answer. Just a PS: `lib` is usually used for third-party libraries or C (or other) language libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's isn't a pythonic way to structure your project.

This is what Kenneth Reitz recommended in 2013 and it's how I use it: https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/repository-structure-and-python.

```py
README.rst
LICENSE
setup.py
requirements.txt
sample/__init__.py
sample/core.py
sample/helpers.py
docs/conf.py
docs/index.rst
tests/test_basic.py
tests/test_advanced.py
```

Inside `sample` (`my_project` in your case) you can separate into categories as you like. E.g. Utils (common functions), Database (read, write), View (user commands), etc. It depends on your project.

As for calling the modules at the same level, you should define them in the `__init__` file of the top hierarchy module which is `sample` in this case.

For example:

`__init__` in _`my_project`

```py
from sample.core import a_Class
from sample.core import a_function
from sample.core import anything
```

then from `/test/test_basic.py` you do:

```py
from sample import a_Class
# or import sample

a = a_Class()  # use the class from core.py
# or a = sample.a_Class()
```

Take a look at the sample module repository: https://github.com/navdeep-G/samplemod